# where case when sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sales table

I wish to do the following select the data date that is available if the top date SalePeriodFrom  = 20181101

(if the top value SalePeriodFrom  **01/11/2018** - first of the month data is available)

if not take the data from the day before (last day of the previous month 31/10/2018)

the code I have is

```
Select *
from Sales

Where case when SalePeriodFrom > DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then   

  (SalePeriodFrom  <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
  and (SalePeriodTo > '20010101' or
  SalePeriodTo is null))

   else (SalePeriodFrom <= DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
  and (SalePeriodTo > '20010101' or
  SalePeriodTo is null)) end
```

I can't seem to get this to work, any ideas please team

Comment: You're trying to use a `CASE` expression as a statement. A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value (that needs to be compared to another expression in the `WHERE` to create a Boolean result). A `CASE` expression doesn't return a Boolean result on its own. For example `CASE ColumnA WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END = 2;`

Comment: T-SQL does not have Boolean values. It has Boolean expressions, but these are only valid in particular contexts. And yes, this is annoying. You can have your `CASE` return a `1` or `0` and check on that, or split the query in two and use a `UNION [ALL]` to combine the results, or figure out universal expressions to compare `SalePeriodFrom` and `SalePeriodTo` to (I can't immediately see what those would be).

Comment: I can't figure out what you want to accomplish.  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to replicate the boolean expressions you have inside your `CASE` expression, however, I can't check this without sample data:

```
SELECT {List of Columns} --You should probably list your columns here
FROM dbo.Sales --Assumed dbo schema
WHERE (SalePeriodFrom > DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
  AND  (SalePeriodTo > '20181101' OR SalePeriodTo IS NULL))
   OR (SalePeriodFrom <= DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
  AND (SalePeriodTo > '20010101' OR SalePeriodTo IS NULL));
```

Like mentioned into the comments on the question, this doesn't use a `CASE` expression at all. Using a `CASE` on your columns would cause the query to become non-SARGable, so (generally) they are best avoided.

Note I've taken out the clause `SalePeriodFrom  <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`. This actually made no sense, as it looked like you were trying to check that the value of `SalePeriodFrom` was both greater than (`>`) and less than or equal to (`<=`) the expression `DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`. It is impossible to something to be greater than something **and** less than or equal to it. For example `1` is greater than `0` but it is not equal or less than it. `0` is less than or equal to `0`, but it is not greater than it.

Comment: this does not seem to work, I have tried similar to answer by serge below. There is data available in the dataset that SalePeriodFrom = 01/11/2018,

Comment: @pete then provide sample data and expected results, like was asked for please. Have you tried altering this example (based on guess work). Maybe it's as simple as using `>=` instead; we can't know without knowing your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the first WHEN condition is always false so you may discard it.

```
SELECT * FROM Sales
WHERE SalePeriodFrom <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND
      (SalePeriodFrom <= DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()) AND 
      (SalePeriodTo > '20010101' OR SalePeriodTo is null))
```

Comment: I mention this is my answer, however, `SalePeriodFrom > DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND SalePeriodFrom <= DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` can never be true.

Comment: @Larnu yes, it's very strange logical expression obfuscated by CASE

Comment: hi this does not seem to work , there is data available in the dataset that SalePeriodFrom = 01/11/2018, it seems to have done the query for all records after the OR . any more ideas please

Comment: hi, this returned no rows, any more ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question logic is really garbled and hard to make sense of. Read it back to yourself, or read it aloud to a co-worker and see if they get what you're on about

My understanding of your requirement is:

If the sales table contains any data from 01-Nov-2018, return all the data with a date of 01-Nov-2018, otherwise return any data with a date of 31-Oct-2018

```
select *
from sales
where SalePeriodFrom = 
    (SELECT MAX(saleperiodfrom) FROM sales WHERE saleperiodfrom IN ('2018-11-01', '2018-10-30'))
```

If there is data for both dates or only 1st Nov, the MAX() will return the 1st Nov date. If there is no data from 1st Nov but there is data from 30th Oct then the MAX will return the 30th Oct date. If there is no data for either date, the max will return nothing and you'll get no data

If I've misunderstood your requirement, please state it more clearly

——————————————————————————————-

Edit:

Or maybe you mean:

If the sales table contains any data with a date 01-Nov-2018, return all the data after midnight on 01-Nov-2018, otherwise return any data after midnight on 31-Oct-2018

```
select *
from sales
where SalePeriodFrom >= 
    (SELECT MAX(saleperiodfrom) FROM sales WHERE saleperiodfrom IN ('2018-11-01', '2018-10-30'))
```

Comment: hi I tried the following  where saleperiodFrom = 
    (SELECT MAX(saleperiodFrom) FROM Sales WHERE saleperiodFrom IN ('2018-11-01', '2018-10-31') and (saleperiodTo> '20010101' or
     ActiveTo is null)) I get no records. to clarify I want the data to go from saleperiodFrom 01/11/2018, if the max value 01/11/2018 has not been entered into the data set yet  then the saleperiodFrom need to go from 31/10/2018 - last day of the previous month. please help / more ideas.. do appreciate

Comment: Make the = into >= instead? You’re not making a lot of sense to be honest..